# Railties 5.0 on Rails 5.0 is not compatible with jquery-scrollto-rails. Bundler can't find compatible gem for Railties 5.0.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to use the scrollTo gem in Rails 5.0 and I am currently having an issue when running Bundle install and after having inserted the gem 'jquery-scrollto-rails' in my gemfile. There is a compatible problem with railties apparently and have no clue to solve it. Is anybody has an idea ? I will appreciate. Thank you.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
railties (= 5.0.2)

In Gemfile:
coffee-rails (~> 4.2) was resolved to 4.2.1, which depends on
  railties (< 5.2.x, >= 4.0.0)

jquery-rails was resolved to 4.3.1, which depends on
  railties (>= 4.2.0)

jquery-scrollto-rails was resolved to 1.4.2, which depends on
  railties (~> 3.1)

rails (~> 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  railties (= 5.0.2)

sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
  railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)

web-console (>= 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.4.0, which depends on
  railties (>= 5.0)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using 
only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Here is my gemfile :

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported 
runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem "jquery-scrollto-rails"
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: 
https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: 
https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'

gem 'font-awesome-sass'

gem 'simple_form'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

gem 'compass-rails'
```

Comment: That gem looks abandoned -- no updates for years. Its [GitHub page](https://github.com/JohnColvin/jquery-scrollto-rails), however, recommends installing bower to get jQuery scrollTo working.

Comment: That's true...Thank youfor you reply